# Appending your <bundle_ID> directory. What is it?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I’m having trouble with writing file to AppSupport Folder in Xcode 5, for iOS 7.
What I’m trying to do:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“somedata.plist”];
if(plistData) {
    NSLog(@"PATH: %@", plistPath);
    BOOL success = [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS: %hhd",success);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR CREATING PLIST: %@",error);
}
```

And I’m getting NO as output:

```
PATH: /var/mobile/Applications/40954....7E3C/Library/Application Support/somedata.plist
SUCCESS: 0
```

Apple Documentation says:

```
Use the Application Support directory constant NSApplicationSupportDirectory, 
appending your <bundle_ID> for: …
```

What means append your bundle_ID? May be there is another path that I should use? NSDocumentDirectory is not suitable for me, because it is a place for user’s files.

Comment: What is in the plist file? Is it always required? How costly is it to recreate?

Comment: Also, NSApplicationSupportDirectory doesn't exist by default so you need to check and create it if required

Comment: It is rarely updating big array of strings basically. If user in offline, that would be a problem. If he online, it might take a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing to `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` is bit more complicated than that,

Follow this [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html) to write files to this directory,

```
- (NSURL*)applicationDirectory
{
    NSString* bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* dirPath = nil;

    // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
    NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                        inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if ([appSupportDir count] > 0)
    {
        // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the
        // Application Support directory
        dirPath = [[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:bundleID];

        //Modified code to write your plist file to the Application support dir
        NSString *plistPath = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“somedata.plist”];

        //Assuming plistData is pre-populated ivar
        //Else add your code to create plistData here 
        if(plistData) {
            BOOL success = [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS: %hhd",success);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR CREATING PLIST: %@",error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for:  [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoter, appreciate if you give feedback to improve the answer.

Comment: You modified the original apple code without testing it. Your function doesn't return anyting.